# SE site-specific chat doesn't work properly for all host values

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=chat.gaming.stackexchange.com doesn't work as expected. I thought it would show me the chatrooms related to Gaming SE, but I only saw the Web Apps SE room. Another user saw the XMPP chatroom and nothing else.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gaming.stackexchange.com, where `host` does not include `chat.`, works correctly.

This wouldn't be too big of a deal except that that first URL was automatically generated when I entered http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/ into my browser by hand.

[image: screenshot with URL-site mismatches highlighted]

Comment: Shoot.  The plot to get more people into the WA chat room has been discovered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&host=chat.gaming.stackexchange.com` is an error, that I shall address currently. In the absence of a *recognised* host, it has then defaulted to webapps, which is the primary site associated with your account.

In my defence, nowhere (AFAIK) *officially* links to chat.gaming.stackexchange.com ;p

But I'll look into it.